# POST csv/Text file using cURL

Tags: python-3.x, curl, flask, flask-restful

How can I send POST request with a csv or a text file to the server running on a `localhost` using `cURL`.

I have tried `curl -X POST -d @file.csv http://localhost:5000/upload` but I get

> {
>       "message": "The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand."
>   }

My server is `flask_restful API`. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are many alternate ways to accomplish this. One way is
I have used the following:

```
curl -F ‘data=@<file_location>’ <URL>
```

Eg. `curl -F data=@data.csv localhost:5000/h`

Your command can also be changed slightly like this

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: text/csv' -d @file.csv http://localhost:5000/upload
```

The above is one of the many ways.It can be sent either as a part of form or data, or multipart, etc. You can refer [Medium Post](https://medium.com/@petehouston/upload-files-with-curl-93064dcccc76)

Comment: Oh, I get it. Thanks a lot. Is there a way to send this csv data with a key so that my server can grab this file with a key name?

Comment: Maybe, you can use --data-binary to include the newline characters in csv file.

Answer (score 2):

Curl's default Content-Type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` so your problem is probably that the data you are POSTing is not actually form data. It might work if you set the content type header properly:

`-H "Content-Type: text/csv"`

Though it does depend on the server.

Comment: Understood. Thank you.