# How to send .csv file using cURL in python

Tags: python, api, csv, curl

I have API and I need to send a .csv file using cURL in python. I do not know how to write this command on python.

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://**************' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'API-AUTH-TOKEN: **************' \
--form 'list=@"/C:/Users/1288956/Downloads/ozon_search_query_test.csv"'
```

- - means I can't show it

Comment: I think this may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50998620/post-csv-text-file-using-curl

Comment: https://curlconverter.com/

Comment: RJ Adriaansen, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

R.J. Adriaansen gave me a good answer: curlconverter.com

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'API-AUTH-TOKEN': '**************',
}

files = {
    'list': ('"/C:/Users/1288956/Downloads/ozon_search_query_test.csv"', open('"/C:/Users/1288956/Downloads/ozon_search_query_test.csv"', 'rb')),
}

response = requests.post('http:///**************', headers=headers, files=files)
```